# Cannot resolve symbol 'ImageReference'

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx, wear-os

For reference, I'm using a clone of [flopsydroid](https://github.com/mauimauer/flopsydroid) to try and test LibGDX on Android Wear. Before doing anything else, I get an error trying to import `android.support.wearable.view.ImageReference` in [MenuGridViewPagerAdapter](https://github.com/mauimauer/flopsydroid/blob/master/wear/src/at/maui/flopsydroid/android/adapter/MenuGridViewPagerAdapter.java). To the best of my knowledge, all libraries are up to date, and classes in the same parent package (e.g. `android.support.wearable.view.GridPagerAdapter`) import without a problem.

I've updated the SDK as much as possible, and cleaned and rebuilt the project (using Intellij IDEA). Are there any other steps I could be taking? Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ImageReference` class has been removed from the latest Android Wear SDK. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/package-summary.html

The method in `GridViewPagerAdapter` that returned an `ImageReference` has been replaced by `getBackgroundForPage(int row, int column)`, which returns a `Drawable` instead. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridPagerAdapter.html#getBackgroundForPage(int,%20int)